# NHibernate creates 2 fields in one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I have the following entities, mapped by code:

**VarRecipeMapping.cs**

```cs
public VarRecipeMapping()
{
    Table("var_recipe");

    // ...

    Bag(x => x.Entries, m =>
    {
        m.Cascade(Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
        m.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);
    },
    a => a.OneToMany());
}
```

**VarRecipeEntryMapping.cs**

```cs
public VarRecipeEntryMapping()
{
    Table("var_recipe_entry");

    // ...

    ManyToOne(x => x.Recipe, m =>
    {
        m.Column("var_recipe_id");
        m.NotNullable(true);
    });
}
```

What annoys me is the resulting database (SQLite): it contains all columns of my entites defined by `Column` **plus an additional, unused `Recipe` column in the `var_recipe_entry` table**.

Obviously generated by NHibernate due to having a field called `Recipe` in the model.

What can I do to get rid of this useless field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

I had to specify the custom name on the "one-to-many" side too.

**VarRecipeMapping.cs**

```cs
public VarRecipeMapping()
{
    Table("var_recipe");

    // ...

    Bag(x => x.Entries, m =>
    {
        // The custom name needs to be specified here too
        m.Key(n => {
            n.Column("var_recipe_id");
        });

        m.Cascade(Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
        m.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);
    },
    a => a.OneToMany());
}
```

**VarRecipeEntryMapping.cs**

```cs
public VarRecipeEntryMapping()
{
    Table("var_recipe_entry");

    // ...

    ManyToOne(x => x.Recipe, m =>
    {
        m.Column("var_recipe_id");
        m.NotNullable(true);
    });
}
```

Comment: Mark this as the answer please.